# Pytorch and batches

Tags: pytorch

I'm having trouble understanding how batches play a role into the Pytorch framework.

In this model:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        # 28x28x1 => 26x26x32
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.d1 = nn.Linear(26 * 26 * 32, 128)
        self.d2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # 32x1x28x28 => 32x32x26x26
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        # flatten => 32 x (32*26*26)
        x = x.flatten(start_dim = 1)
        #x = x.view(32, -1)

        # 32 x (32*26*26) => 32x128
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        # logits => 32x10
        logits = self.d2(x)
        out = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
        return out
```

In the forward definition, we pass in some `x`, ie. aggregated images for a batch from a DataLoader. Here, the `32x1x28x28` dimension indicates that there are 32 images in a batch. Do we just ignore this fact and Pytorch handles applying Conv2d to each sample? The forward propagation seems to be just relative to a single image.

Comment: I'm not sue if I understood you correctly, in case I did not, say so. Basically Pytorch uses matrix multiplication and calculates the output altogether in one go and this includes all images in the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the network is agnostic to batches: The model is designed to classify a *single* image.

So why do we need batches for?
Each model has *weights* (aka parameters) and one needs to *optimize* the weights using the training images so that the model will classify images as correctly as possible.
This optimization process is usually carried out using [Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent): we are using the current values of the weights to classify a *batch* of images. Using the prediction the current model made, and the expected predictions we know should be (the "labels") we can compute a *gradient* of the weights and improve the model.